# Distributing a set of integers where set follows a patttern

Tags: group-theory, functions

Forgive incorrect formatting/language.  My knowledge of mathematical notation is limited.

Is this possible - and, if so, how would I set about coming up with a solution/solution set given the following logic?

`x`=a whole number greater than `y`

`y`=the number of pieces that I want to divide `x` into

`z`=some number less than 1

where the following is true:

```
    ( y₁ + y₂ +y₃ +y₄ +y₅ ) = x & {

        ( y₁ * z ) = y₂ &
        ( y₂ * z ) = y₃ &
        ( y₃ * z ) = y₄ &
        ( y₄ * z ) = y₅ &

}
```

and all of `y₁...y₅` are whole numbers

extra kudos for a solution so that all `y₁...y₅` are *easy* numbers  - that is numbers ending in a 5 or a 0

*note*:  Another alternative solution could involve subtracting rather than taking a percentage of.  In other words, something like `[10,8,6,4,2]=30`, because those numbers add up to 30, and each number is exactly 2 greater than the next.  This seems easier to solve, but I still don't know how to write the function for figuring that out.

*note*: Also, my tags are probably incorrect.  Please change if you see fit.  Thanks.

Comment: The conditions in grey are equivalent to $$y_1(1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4)=360$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want
$$y_1(1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4) =x$$
which means
$$y_1 = x/(1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4)$$ Then you can successively recover
$$y_2 = y_1z = xz/(1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4)$$
$$y_3 = y_2z = xz^2/(1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4)$$
$$y_4 = y_3z = xz^3/(1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4)$$
$$y_5 = y_4z = xz^4/(1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4)$$